# How do I get Zend working with IIS 7.0 (rewrite module v2) and windows 2008?

Tags: zend-framework, iis-7, url-rewriting

My website seems to only load the index page regardless of what path it is given.

Does anyone know of any known issues with getting Zend working correctly with IIS 7.0 (rewrite module v2) and windows 2008?

I'm getting desperate with this and can't seen to find any suitable solutions?

I can put a phpinfo() screen shot on if it helps?

The following information is set in phpinfo()

```
_SERVER["HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL"] /prices/
```

The rewrite seems to work in that sense it always hits the index.php page just sometimes gives a 404 on the homepage and doesnt load the correct views.

Comment: Is it possible something is wrong with your code? htaccess? basepath for your app? On apache I'd talk about your httpd.conf file.

Comment: Could be I'm trying to find out what it could be as all the routing is done within the zend library so not sure what the problem could be within my code though, any ideas?

Comment: My first comment contains 3 ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an issue with the .htaccess file not converting properly from the import function on the modrewrite v2 in IIS.

This is the correct standard rewrite config:

```
<rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Zend Standard Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?route={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

Hope this helps someone